# Exectuting sudo command in one line within a non-tty shell

Tags: linux, privilege-escalation, bash, sudo

I have access to a server via RCE over http. I can send post requests to the server which results in command execution. I am attempting to escalate privileges via sudo (su is not installed).

The server is heavily firewalled with egress filters and there are no writeable directories/files within the web application.

My objective is to experiment with the `sudo` command to escalate privileges but because the command execution is not TTY; I am unable to execute the sudo command.

Is it possible to execute a command like `sudo -S` in a non-TTY shell?

Maybe using python's pty module to spawn `/bin/bash` or `/bin/sh`, but what about a method to just execute a single binary with some parameters passed to it like `sudo -S <command>` within/as a TTY shell?

To summarize: Is there a way to run `sudo` in a single line in a non-TTY shell?

For example I am trying to run sudo with these parameters:

`echo <password> | sudo -u root -S id`

When I execute the above command I receive the following output:

`sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo`

Comment: Can yo uread the output of commands? If so, can you enter what `sudo -ll` prints?

Comment: Does the host have `ssh` installed? If so, you could use `ssh -t localhost sudo ...` to ssh to yourself and execute sudo via tty.

Answer (score 2):

There are probably a few different ways to approach this problem, but I believe I found a simple way around it that is no different from what you'd do normally to [upgrade a shell](https://blog.ropnop.com/upgrading-simple-shells-to-fully-interactive-ttys/) to a full-fledged pty.

First, the reason you are encountering this error is due to the `Defaults requiretty` setting in `/etc/sudoers`. It seems this option is outdated, and is already likely removed/slated to be removed from the default configuration on most distros.

I created a test user "shudo" with password "shudo" who is allowed to sudo to root to run the command `id`, and enabled the `requiretty` option. Here's what happens when "shudo" tries to sudo from a netcat shell:

```
sudo id
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
```

To get around this, let's try a typical PTY upgrade using Python:

```
echo -e "sudo id\nshudo" | python -c 'import pty;pty.spawn("/bin/bash")'
```

There's probably a way to do it with the `-S` option, but it's not needed. This spawns a new PTY to run `/bin/bash`, which receives the sudo command and password as standard in.

Here's the output:

```
echo -e "sudo id\nshudo" | python -c 'import pty;pty.spawn("/bin/bash")'
shudo@mymachine:/tmp$ sudo id
[sudo] password for shudo: 
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

You can see the new shell is spawned, `sudo` is executed, and the command is run as root! Note that this did leave my shell in a bad state since stdin is tied to the pipe, but it should be sufficient for a PoC.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the "sudo" command is trying to invoke the password prompt, however since you're not running a "real" tty / shell, that doesn't work.

[Here is the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38641856) that should fix this, from Stack Overflow.

Comment: Could you provide a example pertaining to this question, if so I will accept your answer.

Comment: This solution does not work because it still prompts for the command to be executed.

Comment: By command, do you mean the argument parameters?

If a password prompt is required by the OS, then you'll need the password to execute it.

Comment: The password is is entered from stdin but the command is not executed correctly.

Comment: Consider including the relevant parts from that link by editing your answer.